# When a horse/cow/sheep/buffalo, etc [freaks out]

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for an animal when it freaks out? *Stampede* is a good word but it seems it's used for a group of animals based on LDOCE. I need a word with the same reaction from the animal but applied to one. Think of this: your horse starts neighing, jumping up and down or running around and you don't know why maybe it heard a gunshot or saw a lion or something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Spooked

is a word which gets used to described animals when they get very frightened and unmanageable.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Just a question to make sure to use it correctly. Is it informal? If yes, is there any neutral or formal way to express this?

Comment: Yuri, you can find plenty of instances online. [This should be enough to get you started](https://www.google.com/search?q=horse+was+spooked).

Comment: Yea, and Im thankful for that I already upvoted Peter. Thanks :)

Comment: For horses and cows, the term panicked is also used. https://www.google.com/?client=firefox-b-ab#q=panicked+horses

Comment: You know the good thing here is you get words in senses that you can't find in a common dictionary like LDOCE. I couldn't find these in million years using the dictionary :) thanks

Comment: **spooked** is good but rather informal. A more "neutral" way to express this idea  would be to say "The creature **took fright**".  **Take** is a super-verb.  You could write a dissertation on it :)

Comment: @TRomano thanks actually it's helpful, too. I can really use it. No pun intended seriously :)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is **shied**, though that one is mostly used for horses and is sometimes less severe than being spooked.

> verb (used without object), shied,shying.
>
> 9. (especially of a horse) to start back or aside, as in fear.

From the [dictionary.com defintion of shied](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shied).